# How do I remove categories from UIUserNotificationSettings?

Tags: ios8, apple-push-notifications

The docs for UIUserNotificationSettings is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationSettings_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIUserNotificationSettings).

Previously, I added a category to the UIMutableUserNotificationCategory and was able to get custom actions/buttons in the system notifications for iOS 8. Now, I want to remove them. I removed that code but when I tested the push notification with that category, the custom action still shows up.

My guess is that the notification settings is saved the the UIUserNotificationSettings which I don't have control over. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app does not seem to reset the notification settings for my app.

How do I get the app to stop responding to custom actions triggered by a category?

Thanks!

PS: An example payload that I used for the push notification which still works after I removed the code from the app:

```
{ "alert": "asdf", "sound": "default", "category": "AN_ACTION" }
```